# Is there a way to break from an array's reduce function in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, break, array-reduce

Is there a way to do something similar to `break` from a `for` loop but in array's `reduce()` function?

E.g. consider I have an array:

```
var flags = [false, false, true, false, false, true, false]
```

... and I need to get a cumulative `||` on them.  With a `for` loop, the following would be possible:

```
var resultByFor = false

for flag in flags {
    if flag {
        resultByFor = true
        break
    }
}
```

... i.e. at the moment we get our first `true` there is no need to finish the loop as the result will be `true` anyway.

With `reduce()`, the following looks quite neat and tidy:

```
var resultByReduce = flags.reduce(false) { $0 || $1 }
```

However, with the array given in the example, the `for` loop body would be executed only 3 times, while `reduce()` function closure would get triggered full 7 times.

Is there a way to make `reduce()` to bail out on 3rd iteration as well (just like it can be done in `for` loop)?

**[UPD]**

I oversimplified the question.  The original problem was more like this:

```
extension Int {
    func isWholeMultiplesOf(base: Int) -> Bool {
        return (self % base) == 0
    }
}

var numbers = [3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 8]

var resultByFor = false

// The loop body will be triggered only 3 times
for number in numbers {
    if number.isWholeMultiplesOf(2) {
        resultByFor = true
        break
    }
}

// The closure of reduce() will be triggered 7 times
var resultByReduce = numbers.reduce(false) {
    $0 || $1.isWholeMultiplesOf(2)
}
```

... i.e. I have an array of objects and I want to know if there is at least one of them that has certain method evaluating to `true`.

Comment: I don't think so. `reduce` like `contains` and `filter` iterates over all items. I think 1st example is a proper one

Comment: you could write that as extension. That would look like reduce but break early.

Comment: Why don't you just use contains?

Comment: Generally, if you find yourself needing to break out of a reduce, you shouldn’t be using a reduce.  It is _much_ better to use a `for` loop than contort yourself into avoid one.  If you don’t like the look of it in your code, wrap it in a generic function along the lines of `contains` or `find`, with an early `return` in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others have suggested, you can use `contains` for this purpose:

```
var flags = [false, false, true, false, false, true, false]
contains(flags, true) //--> true
```

Another option is to use `find` to search for the first instance of what you're looking for, in this case `true`:

```
var flags = [false, false, true, false, false, true, false]    
find(flags, true) // --> 2, returns nil if not found
let containsTrue = (find(flags, true) != nil)
```

Edit: Newer versions of Swift expose these functions on the related collection protocols instead of global functions.

```swift
var flags = [false, false, true, false, false, true, false]
flags.contains(where: { $0 == true })
flags.contains(true) // if checking for a specific element
let index = flags.firstIndex(where: ${ $0 == true }) // --> 2
```

Comment: That's not the new equivalent syntax. You don't need a closure for a `Bool` sequence. `Bool` is `Equatable`. `flags.contains(true)`

Comment: Yeah that's true, but the original question seemed to be simplifying the use case and they were actually interested in providing the block, at least based on the edit made. I'll update mine though

Answer (score 4):

It's not available out of the box in the Swift Standard Library, but you can make it. In [my blog post](http://www.mczarnik.com/2017/04/08/break-out-of-reduce.html) I have described my proposed solution. In your case it'll look like this on the call side:

`flags.reduce(false, { $0 || $1 }, until: { $0 })`

You can give it a try in [that Playground](https://github.com/Czajnikowski/Playgrounds)

Comment: Please include the relevant content from your blog post here, as Stack Overflow policies require. This will help people if your site goes offline indefinitely.

Comment: There you go @idmean

Answer (score 0):

The modern way of tackling your "original problem" is

```swift
[3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 8].contains {
  $0.isMultiple(of: 2)
}
```

There is no `break` for iterated closures, just as there is no `break` allowed in the main body of a function. To mimic it, you need to throw an error.

```swift
for number in numbers {
  guard !number.isMultiple(of: 2) else {
    break
  }

  print(number)
}
```

```swift
try? numbers.forEach {
  guard !$0.isMultiple(of: 2) else {
    struct Error: Swift.Error { }
    throw Error()
  }

  print($0)
}
```